# How to specialise functions of enums?

Tags: rust, dispatch

With the following example code:

```
enum Mode { Mode0(Mode0), Mode1(Mode1) }
struct Mode0 ();
struct Mode1 ();

enum Event { Event0(Event0), Event1(Event1), Event2(Event2) }
struct Event0 ();
struct Event1 ();
struct Event2 ();
    
fn mode_event_(a: Mode, b: Event) {
    match (a, b) {
        (Mode::Mode0(m), Event::Event1(e)) => mode0event1(m, e),
        (Mode::Mode1(m), Event::Event1(e)) => mode1event1(m, e),
        (Mode::Mode1(m), e) => mode1event_(m, e),
        _ => (),
    }
}

fn mode0event1(m: Mode0, e: Event1) {
}

fn mode1event1(m: Mode1, e: Event1) {
}

fn mode1event_(m: Mode1, e: Event) {
}
```

How do I avoid writing `mode_event_()` dispatch functions?

In my case, I have four Modes and fourteen Events.  This results in up to 56 match branches.  I have many functions which need to be despatched on the subtypes of A and B.

What is the idiomatic way to structure this in Rust?

I want the dispatch to be decided on the function signatures, e.g. `a0b1(a: A0s, b: B1s)` and not in a manually written dispatch function which can get out of sync with the declared functions.  i.e I could add `fn mode0event0(m: Mode0, e: Event0)` and it would not be called unless I remembered to add it to (all of) the dispatch function(s).

Comment: This may be relevant: https://docs.rs/enum_dispatch/0.3.6/enum_dispatch/

Comment: "I could add fn mode0event0(m: Mode0, e: Event0) and it would not be called unless I remembered to add it to (all of) the dispatch function(s)." this would not compile cause you added a variant to the enum

Comment: just write a macro

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks for commenting.  re: "this would not compile cause you added a variant to the enum " unfortunately it would, as I both need a default and a functions which take any variant of the enums, such as `(Mode::Mode1(m), e) => mode1event_(m, e)`.

Comment: Maybe [this crate](https://github.com/fcard/multimethods.rs) can help?